# How to access a capturing group from regexp.ReplaceAllFunc?

Tags: go

How can I access a capture group from inside ReplaceAllFunc()?

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "regexp"
)

func main() {
    body := []byte("Visit this page: [PageName]")
    search := regexp.MustCompile("\\[([a-zA-Z]+)\\]")

    body = search.ReplaceAllFunc(body, func(s []byte) []byte {
        // How can I access the capture group here?
    })

    fmt.Println(string(body))
}
```

The goal is to replace `[PageName]` with `<a href="/view/PageName">PageName</a>`.

This is the last task under the "Other tasks" section at the bottom of the [Writing Web Applications](https://golang.org/doc/articles/wiki/) Go tutorial.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to get group in `ReplaceAllFunc`, you can use `ReplaceAllString` to get the subgroup.

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "regexp"
)

func main() {
    body := []byte("Visit this page: [PageName]")
    search := regexp.MustCompile("\\[([a-zA-Z]+)\\]")

    body = search.ReplaceAllFunc(body, func(s []byte) []byte {
        // How can I access the capture group here?
        group := search.ReplaceAllString(string(s), `$1`)

        fmt.Println(group)

        // handle group as you wish
        newGroup := "<a href='/view/" + group + "'>" + group + "</a>"
        return []byte(newGroup)
    })

    fmt.Println(string(body))
}
```

And when there are many groups, you are able to get each group by this way, then handle each group and return desirable value.

Comment: I'll pick this as the new accepted answer as it is closer to what I was looking for.

Answer (score 8):

I agree that having access to capture group while inside of your function would be ideal, I don't think it's possible with `regexp.ReplaceAllFunc`.
Only thing that comes to my mind right now regard how to do this with that function is this:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "regexp"
)

func main() {
    body := []byte("Visit this page: [PageName] [OtherPageName]")
    search := regexp.MustCompile("\\[[a-zA-Z]+\\]")
    body = search.ReplaceAllFunc(body, func(s []byte) []byte {
        m := string(s[1 : len(s)-1])
        return []byte("<a href=\"/view/" + m + "\">" + m + "</a>")
    })
    fmt.Println(string(body))
}
```

**EDIT**

There is one other way I know how to do what you want. First thing you need to know is that you can specify non capturing group using syntax `(?:re)` where `re` is your regular expression. This is not essential, but will reduce number of not interesting matches.

Next thing to know is [regexp.FindAllSubmatcheIndex](http://golang.org/pkg/regexp/#Regexp.FindAllSubmatchIndex). It will return slice of slices, where each internal slice represents ranges of **all** submatches for given matching of regexp.

Having this two things, you can construct somewhat generic solution:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "regexp"
)

func ReplaceAllSubmatchFunc(re *regexp.Regexp, b []byte, f func(s []byte) []byte) []byte {
    idxs := re.FindAllSubmatchIndex(b, -1)
    if len(idxs) == 0 {
        return b
    }
    l := len(idxs)
    ret := append([]byte{}, b[:idxs[0][0]]...)
    for i, pair := range idxs {
        // replace internal submatch with result of user supplied function
        ret = append(ret, f(b[pair[2]:pair[3]])...)
        if i+1 < l {
            ret = append(ret, b[pair[1]:idxs[i+1][0]]...)
        }
    }
    ret = append(ret, b[idxs[len(idxs)-1][1]:]...)
    return ret
}

func main() {
    body := []byte("Visit this page: [PageName] [OtherPageName][XYZ]     [XY]")
    search := regexp.MustCompile("(?:\\[)([a-zA-Z]+)(?:\\])")

    body = ReplaceAllSubmatchFunc(search, body, func(s []byte) []byte {
        m := string(s)
        return []byte("<a href=\"/view/" + m + "\">" + m + "</a>")
    })

    fmt.Println(string(body))
}
```

Comment: Yep, that's the workaround I had in mind as well. Using the capture group would have been a more elegant solution, though. Too bad we can't do that with `ReplaceAllFunc()`...

Answer (score 0):

You have to call `ReplaceAllFunc` first and within the function call `FindStringSubmatch` on the same regex again. Like:

```
func (p parser) substituteEnvVars(data []byte) ([]byte, error) {
    var err error
    substituted := p.envVarPattern.ReplaceAllFunc(data, func(matched []byte) []byte {
        varName := p.envVarPattern.FindStringSubmatch(string(matched))[1]
        value := os.Getenv(varName)
        if len(value) == 0 {
            log.Printf("Fatal error substituting environment variable %s\n", varName)
        }

        return []byte(value)
    });
    return substituted, err
}
```